# PKCS11: export insensitive and extractable key

Tags: key, token, pkcs#11, hsm

I generate a derived key that is extractable and insensitive. I want to export it out of  the token and see byes of it. how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the value of the `CKA_VALUE` attribute of the key object using the `C_GetAttributeValue()` function.